# Completeness Relations of Polarization Vectors in QCD

Tags: quantum-field-theory, polarization, quantum-chromodynamics, yang-mills

What are the completeness relations of the polarization vectors of (external) particles in QCD amplitude calculation?
(I assume the polarization vectors depend on the gauge and even so still have some arbitrariness. But what is conventional?)

Answer (score 1):

As can be derived from BRST symmetry, in SU(N) Yang-Mills theory, an external (massless) gluon with momentum (k0,k1,k2,k3) can only have polarizations (0,e1,e2,e3) such that (e1,e2,e3) and (k1,k2,k3) are orthogonal. Or, to be more precise, the polarization can be any vector, but its projection onto the space spanned by (1,0,0,0) and (0,k1,k2,k3) does not contribute to the amplitude. This is a consequence of gauge invariance.

So, if one chooses the set polarization vectors to be orthonormal (which is just a convenient choice but not a necessity!), then the completeness relation gives a projection onto the directions orthogonal to the momentum. For example, if the momentum is (k,0,0,k), then one can choose left- and right-handed polarizations eL=(0,1,-i,0) and eR=(0,-1,-i,0), and then a completeness relation gives the matrix

$$\begin{pmatrix}
0& 0&  0&  0\\
0&  1&  1&  0\\
0&  1&  1&  0\\
0&  0&  0&  0
\end{pmatrix}$$